Madhabs and talfiq?
So I follow the shafii madhab for most stuff but I have a problem with incontince for after peeing and in Maliki madhab says that it doesn’t break wudhu and if I follow this would this be considered talfiq or is it okay

Alhamdulillah,
Following a different madhab on specific issues as long as it is not done out of mere desire or whims, but due to a real need or difficulty in following one's own madhab is not problematic according to the correct view.
In your case, if you genuinely face a lot of difficulty and hardship in following the Shafi'i ruling regarding urinary incontinence breaking wudu, and the Maliki view provides a valid concession that makes it significantly easier for you, then some scholars may permit following the Maliki position on this particular issue without it being considered talfiq.
That said, the safer and more precautionary stance would be to continue following the Shafi'i view, even if it entails hardship, unless you consult with a qualified Shafi'i scholar who can guide you on whether your specific circumstances warrant an exception or not.
And Allah knows best!
